# Updating Fragment UI after async http request

Tags: java, android, http

I am using loop4j for HttpAsync get request.

I am invoking the request from a fragment:

```
RestHttpClientUsage.registerUser(m_context);
```

This is my rest client code:

```
public static void registerUser(Context context) throws JSONException 
{   
    RestHttpClient.get("?Operation=RegisterUser" , params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() 
    {                   
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) 
        {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,String responseString, Throwable throwable) 
        {
            ...
        }

    });
}
```

My question is how can i access the calling fragment from my onSuccess/onFailure callbacks?

I need to call my fragment UpdateUI after the call finishes.

Can i somehow get the fragment from the context object?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a private `BroadcastReceiver` to update the UI. Here goes the declaration for `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    // Declare UI elements
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

    // Initialize elements in onCreate

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("UPDATE_MY_FRAGMENT");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // Read data from intent.getExtras()
            // update UI elements
        }
    }
}
```

And send an `intent` from `registerUser` to the private `BrodcastReceiver`:

```
public static void registerUser(final Context context) throws JSONException 
{   
    RestHttpClient.get("?Operation=RegisterUser" , params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() 
    {                   
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("UPDATE_MY_FRAGMENT");
            // pass data using intent.putExtra based on response
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,String responseString, Throwable throwable) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("UPDATE_MY_FRAGMENT");
            // pass data using intent.putExtra based on response
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply serialize the response (the json object/array in this case) to a global variable or a POJO,then you can call the UI from outside the loop4j context.

does this make sense to you?

Comment: Saving the data is not my problem, my problem is how to call my fragment ui update right after finishing handling the http resopnse

Comment: Use an interface to do a callback, your fragment must implement that interface, then look if there is a way to send that callback to where you handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

because it delivers the response on UI thread(you create request on UI) I think you can do it like:

```
callingFragment.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentBytag("your calling fragment tag").updatUI;
```